# Dojo mysteriously, persistently blanked on page

Tags: javascript, dojo, microsoft-edge

We use the dojo framework on our websites. A client has called in a panic saying their sales from users of Microsoft Edge have completely dropped off. I've found that in that browser, intermittently, the `dojo` variable is null after page load. So of course no interaction works for those users, so of course no sales.

But in the course of testing I found this astonishing thing in devtools:

[image: dojo variable refuses to be set to anything]

I don't even know how I would do that if I *wanted* to do it. So I want to track this down but I have no clue what to look for. I might've suspected some weird, recurring `setInterval` code, but I would not have thought that could get between the two statements on that last console line.

There's a script line just before the `</body>` tag where I'm able to put a breakpoint. At that point, `dojo` is set as the framework as expected. So some code that loads after page load is doing it.

(EDIT: I'd be willing to do iterative, brute force breakpoints if I could. But I only have access to Edge via BrowserStack, and trying to set useful breakpoints in minified code is very difficult in Edge's dev tools.)

1. Does anyone have a suggestion what sort of thing I should look for?
2. How to debug for this? Is there a client-exposed variable where you can see the functions set to the document's onload, or a way I can put breakpoints in them?
3. I attempted using a `watch()` shim in console to watch for the dojo object being changed, but didn't have much luck with that. (but might have done it incorrectly, so if this is an idea, I might need help with proper implementation).

EDIT: There's also this, if this helps make any sense of it. After I delete `dojo`, setting it works as expected.

[image: dojo back to normal after deleting it]

Comment: You could set breakpoints or add some debugger to debug your Javascript code, please refer to [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp). And, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT: the code was minimized and I only had access to Edge via Browserstack, so I only had Microsoft's devtools available to me. Extremely difficult to try to place useful breakpoints.

And no, I couldn't post it exactly because I had no idea where the problem was or how to reproduce it (except for loading every js file that was being loaded on the site).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know what the specific problem is, but someone has at least given me a way in which this is possible:

`window.__defineGetter__('dojo', function(){ return null })`

This doesn't exist in the original code, but at least now I see how it's possible at all. The person who gave me this suggests that the code might be trying to get and protect its own copy of dojo, but something about it goes wrong in Edge.